# How to mount dropper post to Scott Scale without removing BB?

Tags: mountain-bike, seatpost, dropper

Do you know an easy way to install a dropper to Scott Scale 920 without removing bottom bracket?

The frame looks like this:
https://www.scott-sports.com/dk/en/product/scott-scale-920-bike

And the dopper is this model:
https://www.pro-bikegear.com/pl/mtb/seatposts/tharsis-dropper-post-100

The wire inserted through hole near head tube probably passes the bottom bracket but continues to down tube instead of seat tube (the angle is very high). I have no tools and experience to remove the bottom bracket. I'm looking for a way to install the dropper without removing BB. Which ways have you used and worked?

Comment: Looks to me that there is a port on the down tube for it to exit and one on the seat tube for it to to go back in, no need to worry about BB.  Likely find there are channel guides inside the frame to route the cable outer so should be just a case of pushing it through from the head tube and it will pop out for you